# Problem compiling a .sln file with Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio

First thing when I try to run the application (I just downloaded it from CodeProject, right [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/codetextbox.aspx)), I get this error:

> The name Resource does not exist in the current context

So when I double click the error it takes me to this code:

```
private Image mp_CodeImage_Class = Resource._class;
```

But there is a class called Resource but is in a file called *Resource.Designer.cs*, and this file is in a resource file called *Resource.resx*. When I check the properties of  *Resource.resx*, Build Action is set to Embedded Resource and Custom Tool is set to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator. I'm just saying this details in case they help you find a solution because I know nothing about resources, just almost never use them. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Just got me VS Professional and got the same errors.......

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For one, you can't open .sln files (which are VS solutions) in the express versions.

So what you will need to do is open the project file (.csproj), compile it, close that project and then copy the dll which you've just compiled into your project in which you want to use the control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the same error when trying to compile the .csproj file. But anyway if I can't open VS solutions with the express version why does it let me open it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I've not got the express version installed at the moment to check for you.

Comment: Express can open .sln files just fine.

Comment: By bad, I was under the impression that the Express versions couldn't do full on VS solutions. Did this change in 2010 versions? I appologise :-)

Comment: I find that it does open sln files. However I had to use right mouse click to select the application under Windows 7. Double clicking it doesn't open for some reason.